# GSON: Illegal Argument exception when converting a json string to a Java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm working with the Youtube API. I can convert the java Object to a json string. But when I try to reverse it (json string to java object) it throws an exception: `Can not set com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThreadSnippet field com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThread.snippet to java.util.LinkedHashMap`. Why do I get this error and how to fix it?

This works:

```
  CommentThread commentThread = getItSomehow()
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String jsonStr = gson.toJson( commentThread );
```

Reverse throws the exception:

```
 CommentThread fromJson = gson.fromJson( jsonStr, CommentThread.class );
```

Here is the CommentThread class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public final class CommentThread extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {

  /**
   * Etag of this resource.
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key
  private java.lang.String etag;

  /**
   * The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the comment thread.
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key
  private java.lang.String id;

  /**
   * Identifies what kind of resource this is. Value: the fixed string "youtube#commentThread".
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key
  private java.lang.String kind;

  /**
   * The replies object contains a limited number of replies (if any) to the top level comment found
   * in the snippet.
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key
  private CommentThreadReplies replies;

  /**
   * The snippet object contains basic details about the comment thread and also the top level
   * comment.
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key
  private CommentThreadSnippet snippet;

  /**
   * Etag of this resource.
   * @return value or {@code null} for none
   */
  public java.lang.String getEtag() {
    return etag;
  }

  /**
   * Etag of this resource.
   * @param etag etag or {@code null} for none
   */
  public CommentThread setEtag(java.lang.String etag) {
    this.etag = etag;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the comment thread.
   * @return value or {@code null} for none
   */
  public java.lang.String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  /**
   * The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the comment thread.
   * @param id id or {@code null} for none
   */
  public CommentThread setId(java.lang.String id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Identifies what kind of resource this is. Value: the fixed string "youtube#commentThread".
   * @return value or {@code null} for none
   */
  public java.lang.String getKind() {
    return kind;
  }

  /**
   * Identifies what kind of resource this is. Value: the fixed string "youtube#commentThread".
   * @param kind kind or {@code null} for none
   */
  public CommentThread setKind(java.lang.String kind) {
    this.kind = kind;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * The replies object contains a limited number of replies (if any) to the top level comment found
   * in the snippet.
   * @return value or {@code null} for none
   */
  public CommentThreadReplies getReplies() {
    return replies;
  }

  /**
   * The replies object contains a limited number of replies (if any) to the top level comment found
   * in the snippet.
   * @param replies replies or {@code null} for none
   */
  public CommentThread setReplies(CommentThreadReplies replies) {
    this.replies = replies;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * The snippet object contains basic details about the comment thread and also the top level
   * comment.
   * @return value or {@code null} for none
   */
  public CommentThreadSnippet getSnippet() {
    return snippet;
  }

  /**
   * The snippet object contains basic details about the comment thread and also the top level
   * comment.
   * @param snippet snippet or {@code null} for none
   */
  public CommentThread setSnippet(CommentThreadSnippet snippet) {
    this.snippet = snippet;
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public CommentThread set(String fieldName, Object value) {
    return (CommentThread) super.set(fieldName, value);
  }

  @Override
  public CommentThread clone() {
    return (CommentThread) super.clone();
  }

}
```

Below is the details of the exception.

```
Throwable: Can not set com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThreadSnippet field com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThread.snippet to java.util.LinkedHashMap
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThreadSnippet field com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CommentThread.snippet to java.util.LinkedHashMap
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setFieldValue(FieldInfo.java:245)
    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setValue(FieldInfo.java:206)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:103)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:47)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:146)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:721)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:670)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:642)
    at sam.ut.CommentThreads.handleCommentsThreads(CommentThreads.java:157)
    at sam.ut.CommentThreads.DownloadCommentsForThisVideo(CommentThreads.java:84)
    at sam.ut.CommentThreads.main(CommentThreads.java:66)
```

**EDIT**: And here is the JSON:

```
{
  "etag": "\"0Fu6lI6VPLdRMlQU3wwNcowdAUs/F7bYskj8z3daRWhUSU5zInnZkqw\"",
  "id": "z12wxpxozzy1tdxop04cjd1rjzq4cp2jgfw",
  "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
  "snippet": {
    "canReply": true,
    "isPublic": true,
    "topLevelComment": {
      "etag": "\"0Fu6lI6VPLdRMlQU3wwNcowdAUs/PzVv_VFrN7CZoVSIIlPnVsEIwE0\"",
      "id": "z12wxpxozzy1tdxop04cjd1rjzq4cp2jgfw",
      "kind": "youtube#comment",
      "snippet": {
        "authorChannelId": {
          "value": "UCOjTszsvhfAKFQprwN3ETLQ"
        },
        "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOjTszsvhfAKFQprwN3ETLQ",
        "authorDisplayName": "Spruce Moose Arts",
        "authorGoogleplusProfileUrl": "https://plus.google.com/102869292172467105853",
        "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-eJGw19enrkQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAyg/khd3HglROx4/photo.jpg?sz=50",
        "canRate": true,
        "likeCount": 0,
        "publishedAt": "2016-06-13T22:49:52.000Z",
        "textDisplay": "The man behind the camera which recorded this, must be very shaky, \ncondsidering the amount of warp stabilization on this video :P Also, i \nthink this is a matter of personal taste. I personally think the car WITH \npol filter looked much better.",
        "updatedAt": "2016-06-13T22:49:52.000Z",
        "videoId": "YcZkCnPs45s",
        "viewerRating": "none"
      }
    },
    "totalReplyCount": 0,
    "videoId": "YcZkCnPs45s"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late on the subject, but deciding to reply in case this thread is hit by anyone in the future. I ran into the same error, and it seems it's because of the way a `CommentThread` object is marshalled. Very strange. I created a work around to rebuild the `youtube#commentThread` object kind. The JSON you have is correct and enough to build the `youtube@commentThread` from the separate pieces. You'll need to deconstruct the JSON. Let's say you have a helper method called `convertModelFromFile` that will help you map each separate object or piece required to rebuild the `youtube@commentThread`. It can be written such as:

```java
public static <T> T convertModelFromFile(String fileName, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    return objectMapper.readValue(new File(fileName), clazz);
}
```

After deconstructing your json and adding each part that makes up a CommentThread into a separate json file, you can simply pass the file and which part you are trying to recreate. Here's an example of a json file with a `CommentThreadSnippet` and the accompanying `parseCommentThreadSnippet()` method. The other pieces follow the same pattern:

```json
{
  "snippet": {
    "canReply": true,
    "channelId": "UCsBjURrPoezykLs9EqgamOA",
    "isPublic": true
  }
}
```

Using the CommentThreadSnippet json above that'll be in it's own file, you can utilize the helper method to create a CommentThreadSnippet object.

```java
private CommentThreadSnippet parseCommentThreadSnippet() throws IOException {
    return TestHelper.convertModelFromFile(COMMENT_THREAD_WITH_SNIPPET_JSON_FILE, CommentThreadSnippet.class);
}
```

After you've deconstructed each piece into it's own file and created the accompanying methods to marshall the json and map it to the object you're trying to recreate (each object required to build a valid CommentThread) you can do the work and put it together:

```java
commentThread = parseCommentThread();
commentThreadSnippet = parseCommentThreadSnippet();
commentThread.setSnippet(commentThreadSnippet);
topLevelComment = parseTopLevelComment();
commentThread.getSnippet().setTopLevelComment(topLevelComment);
commentSnippet = parseCommentSnippet();
commentThread.getSnippet().getTopLevelComment().setSnippet(commentSnippet);
```

In the above, you're simply rebuilding the `CommentThread` from the separate objects that make up `CommentThread`. There's plenty of room for creativity and making this better, but I hope this serves as a sufficient work-around for your needs!

Comment: I think your answer could be improved if you [edit] it and post some code demonstrating how to perform the steps you outlined.

Comment: @Abra I agree. I updated the answer with some code to make the solution a bit more clear. Thanks!